# Find files recursively that are older than one year and not owned by a specific user

Tags: linux, find, xargs

I'm trying to find any files on a specific mount that are older than one year and do not belong to a specific user.  This is the command I'm using (within the root directory of the mount):

```
find . ! -user username -mtime +365 -type f | xargs ls -al > /tmp/list
```

I'm piping this through xargs because I need to know the absolute path and size for each result.  I do get results, but a number of files seem to be missing.

Could someone give me a hand?  What am I missing?

Comment: The command looks OK to me. But doesn't the `-ls` option to `find` show the full path and size?

Comment: Or `-printf "%p %s\n"`

Comment: Do the files that are missing have anything in common? `xargs` will have problems with files that have whitespace in their names. Use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to deal with that. The `-ls` option also won't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I think that the issue was indeed whitespace.  Using the -ls option is working great for my purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's not exactly the same thing as piping to `xargs ls -al`,
the `-ls` flag of `find` itself might be enough for your and simplify the command a bit:

```
find . ! -user username -mtime +365 -type f -ls > /tmp/list
```

If you think a file is missing, look at what `stat` says about it.
Keep in mind that `-mtime` is a condition concerning modification time.
There's also inode change time, and access time.

Comment: Most Unix filesystems don't have creation time. There's access time, modification time, and inode change time.

Comment: Fantastic.  I'm not sure exactly what about piping everything through xargs was messing up the process, but your command did the job perfectly.  Thanks, @janos!